# State that should have been updated in ReactNative is not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to save the input text to a state and use handleSave to create an item, but when I run handleSave, the console only outputs {name: "",description: "",} before it is updated.
The console.log with useEffect outputs the updated state for each input, but I still cannot get the updated state with handleSave.
I would appreciate it if you could tell me if you know how to improve it.

CreateItem.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { styles } from "style/style";
import CloseIcon from "icons/Close";
import InputText from "utils/InputText";

const CreateItem = ({ navigation }: { navigation: any }) => {

  const [item, setItem] = useState({
    name: "",
    description: "",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (name: string, value: string) => {
    setItem({ ...item, [name]: value });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
          style={{
            padding: 12,
            margin: -12,
          }}
        >
          <CloseIcon size={24} color="#000" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button title="save" onPress={handleSave} color="#000" />
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(item);
  }, [item]);

  const handleSave = () => {
    console.log(newItem); 
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.formGroup}>
            <Text style={styles.formLabel}>Name</Text>
            <InputText
              name="name"
              placeholder="Enter Name"
              value={item.name}
              onChangeText={(text) => handleInputChange("name", text)}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.formGroup}>
            <Text style={styles.formLabel}>description</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.formInputMultiLine}
              placeholder="Enter description"
              multiline={true}
              value={item.description}
              onChangeText={(text) => handleInputChange("description", text)}
            />
          </View>
    </View>
```

InputText.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput } from "react-native";
import { styles } from "../style/style";

interface InputTextProps {
  name: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  keyboardType?: "default" | "numeric" | "email-address" | "phone-pad";
  value?: string;
  onChangeText?: (text: string) => void;
}

const InputText = ({
  name = "name",
  placeholder = "Enter text",
  keyboardType = "default",
  value = "",
  onChangeText,
}: InputTextProps) => {
  const [borderColor, setBorderColor] = useState("#EFEFEF");

  const onFocus = () => {
    setBorderColor("#c09969");
  };

  const onBlur = () => {
    setBorderColor("#EFEFEF");
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        style={[styles.formInput, { borderBottomColor: borderColor }]}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        keyboardType={keyboardType}
        value={value}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onBlur={onBlur}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default InputText;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, newItem is not declared in your code. When navigation setOption function is called the item value will be replaced to the current constant value in the handleSave function.
It might be not efficient to process the screen component data in the navigation header, it would be better you have header component inside the screen component.
I think it will help to fix the current issue with your current code.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
          style={{
            padding: 12,
            margin: -12,
          }}
        >
          <CloseIcon size={24} color="#000" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
      headerRight: () => (
        <Button title="save" onPress={handleSave} color="#000" />
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation, item]);
```

It's just adding item in useEffect condition.

Comment: Thank you!
I was able to solve the problem successfully!
Thank you so much!